# How to match pattern with numbers or numbers and a single dash using regular expression with multiple lines

Tags: c#, regex

I try to get a list of part numbers which should contain 4 letters min and have only numbers or numbers with a single dash `724-234`,`2342`,`72450-924`, and `72995-1` from multiple lines text. I have tried a few possibilities but either I got nothing, got single numbers, or just spaces. It got better when I split the text into multiple lines and process each line but it is very slow. Any help will be appreciated.

```
1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7
REFERENCE ONLY
SOME TEXT TEXT
724-234
SOME TEXT TEXT
THIS IS ANOHTER PARTH 2342
""
72450-924
SOME TEXT TEXT SOME TEXT TEXT
3dsRAr
72995-1
```

```
        void WritePartNumber(string input)
        {
            string pattern = @"^[0-9-]*$";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(input))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(match.Value);
            }
                            
        }
```

Comment: Maybe you can try `[0-9]+[-]{0,1}[0-9]*`.

Comment: You may want to check out https://regexbuddy.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex pattern might be slightly more performant than what you currently have:

```
\b[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)*\b
```

The reason for this is that the above pattern more precisely targets what you are trying to match.

```
void WritePartNumber(string input)
{
    string pattern = @"\b[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)*\b";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
    foreach (Match match in rgx.Matches(input))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(match.Value);
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this would be more performant?

Comment: @t.karalis It might not be terribly faster, but it is the more correct regex pattern to use.

Comment: No doubt the pattern is more correct, just wondering if there were any performance gains and why. Thanks for the edit as well. Apart from that I'm not sure what else the OP could do to increase speed.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps me save at least 2-3 hours each week as I need to work with a large number of PDF files (I extract the text from pdf).